# unable to open market place in spring tool suite 3.9 version

Tags: eclipse, google-play

I am not able to open Eclipse marketplace in spring tool suite 3.9 version. I also tried the `windows>preferences>general>network connections` and changed the active provider to manual and clicked on apply, again restarted the spring tool suite and opened the eclipse market place but it is not opening.

[market place is not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO64B.png)

[after changing to manual also it is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCeTI.png)

Comment: Uou have all of the proxy methods enabled but not defined. That can't be right.

Comment: You're using outdated Eclipse/STS (unclear, how many releases you are behind) and there was an Marketplace issue when the installation path contains spaces. Is that the case?